# What permissions are needed to deploy a report project in VS2005?

Tags: reporting-services

When I try to deploy reports to a newly installed SSRS 2005 server (remote server) I get the following error in VS2005:

The permissions granted to user 'CEINTERNAL\IUSR_COMPELLENT01' are insufficient for performing this operation.

**What permissions are needed to deploy a report project in VS2005?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign either the Admin or Publisher role to CEINTERNAL\IUSR_COMPELLENT01 to the root folder in the Report Manager hierarchy.

Hope this helps,

Bill